# MacBook Pro Boot camp assistant not enough space on start disk

Tags: macos, time-machine, bootcamp, disk-utility

I'm getting the "not enough space on start disk" when trying to use boot camp-assistant.

I have disabled auto time machine and removed the drive.
I have used the command `sudo tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 999999999999`

None of this worked.

The output of command `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits` is:

[image]

It doesn't look right that the recommended minimum is 250 GB? What can I do about this?

*Update*

Have 90GB available.

Answer (score 1):

Just unchecking "Back Up Automatically" in System Preferences ; Time Machine
fixed it for me.